# How to evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\:\frac{2n+1}{2n(n+1)^2}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

**Note:** Similar questions have been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2574204/evaluation-of-sum-n-a-infty-frac12nn1-and-sum-n-1-infty-frac12n) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1331461/does-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac2n1n2n12-converge), but this is quite different.

I am trying to evaluate

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\:\frac{2n+1}{2n(n+1)^2} \quad (1)$$

---

I re-wrote the fraction as $$ \frac{2n+1}{2n(n+1)^2} = \frac1{2(n+1)} \cdot \frac{2n+1}{n(n+1)}= \frac1{2(n+1)} \left( \frac1n + \frac1{n+1} \right) = \frac1{2} \left( \frac1{n(n+1)} + \frac1{(n+1)^2} \right) = \frac12 \left( \left( \frac1n -\frac1{(n+1)} \right) + \frac1{(n+1)^2} \right)$$

Hence

$$(1) = \frac12 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\:  \left( \frac1n -\frac1{(n+1)} \right) + \frac12 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\:\frac1{(n+1)^2} = \frac12\lim_{n \to \infty}1-\frac1{n+1}+\frac{\pi^2}{12} = \frac{\pi^2}{12} + \frac12$$

Therefore

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\:\frac{2n+1}{2n(n+1)^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{12} + \frac12$$

---

I am unsure about $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\:\frac1{(n+1)^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{12} $$

We know the basic p-series $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\:\frac1{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6} $$

Is this solution correct?

Comment: The sum with $1/(n+1)^2$ is just the same as $1/n^2$ starting at index $n=2$ so it is $\pi^2/6-1$. Also say your series term is $\sim 1/n^2$ with positive terms so convergent, so you can rearrange as will below.

Comment: Take $i=n+1$. Then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(n+1)^2}=\sum_{i=2}^\infty\frac1{i^2}=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac1{m^2}-\frac1{1^2}=\frac{\pi^2}6-1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As has been already pointed out in the comments,
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} = \frac{1}{4} + \frac 19 + ... = \frac{\pi^2}{6}-1$$
Therefore, your solution would be
$$\frac{1}{2}\left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1n - \frac {1}{n+1} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right) = \frac 12 \left( 1 + \frac{\pi^2}{6} - 1\right) = \boxed{\frac{\pi^2}{12}}$$

Answer (score 1):

1). $\frac{2n+1}{2n(n+1)^2}=\frac{n+n+1}{2n(n+1)^2}=\frac{1}{2(n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{2n(n+1)}$
So
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\geq1}{}\frac{2n+1}{2n(n+1)^2}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\geq1}{}\frac{1}{n(n+1)}\\
=\frac{1}{2}(\zeta(2)-1)+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\geq1}{}\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\\
=\frac{1}{2}(\zeta(2)-1)+\frac{1}{2}\\
=\frac{(\pi)^2}{12}\\
\end{align*}